# r markdown not compiling

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

So I have been using R Markdown for quite some time, but now when I try to knit my document, it fails. The following error message comes up:

> LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list
>   environment.

I am not sure as to why this happens since it was working for me before. I have two shortcuts in the preamble of my document:

1. `\newcommand{\benum}{\begin{enumerate}}`
2. `\newcommand{\eenum}{\end{enumerate}}`

I have a feeling that this could be the cause of my problems, but it is frustrating as I have used these for such a long time before this with no trouble.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Here is a minimal document that I made. This small document will not knit, and the same error message described above comes up.

````
---
title: "Minimal Document"
author: Aiden Kenny
date: Friday, 09/21/2018
header-includes: 
  - #\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
  - \newcommand{\benum}{\begin{enumerate}}
  - \newcommand{\eenum}{\end{enumerate}}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: margin=1in 
output: pdf_document
---

\newpage

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 10, fig.height = 5, echo = TRUE)
library(mosaic)
library(knitr)
library(scatterplot3d)
```

1. Here is a sample of some code I found online. The code chunk by 
itself will run fine, so that is not the issue.


```{r, echp=FALSE}
require(stats); require(graphics)
plot(cars, xlab = "Speed (mph)", ylab = "Stopping distance (ft)",
 las = 1)
lines(lowess(cars$speed, cars$dist, f = 2/3, iter = 3), col = "red")
title(main = "cars data")
plot(cars, xlab = "Speed (mph)", ylab = "Stopping distance (ft)",
     las = 1, log = "xy")
title(main = "cars data (logarithmic scales)")
lines(lowess(cars$speed, cars$dist, f = 2/3, iter = 3), col = "red")
summary(fm1 <- lm(log(dist) ~ log(speed), data = cars))
opar <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2), oma = c(0, 0, 1.1, 0),
            mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 2.1, 1.1))
plot(fm1)
par(opar)
```
````

***EDIT:***
 I have been playing around with this, and this seems to be part of the issue:

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item Using the default enumerate/itemize commands

\item DO work!

\end{enumerate}
```

but...

```
\benum

\item Using the shortcut commands I made

\item DO NOT work!

\eenum
```

When I try to run the code chunks individually, they compile just fine and produce the desired graphs, so I suspect that this is an issue with LaTeX. But I am not a tex person so I am not sure.

The reason I had initially made these shortcut command was so that I could use chunks of R code in this type of environment (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210003/how-can-i-nest-a-code-chunk-within-an-enumerate-environment-when-using-r-markdow).

As mentioned by someone below, this could have to do with something called Pandoc?

Thanks!

Comment: I am surprised you need those short cuts in a RMarkdown document. There are places where raw LaTeX code is needed, but I never encountered that for enumerations. Anyway, in order to solve this you should build a [mcve]. Most likely you will spot the error there. If not, then please [edit] your post and include the minimal example.

Comment: I have edited the post so that there is a minimal example document that will not knit on my computer.

Comment: weird, this knits fine for me using both knitr and sweave, pdflatex and Xelatx

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. My suspicion is that this has to do with the LaTeX on my computer, not R Studio; as I said before, the individual code chunks knit just fine, and the issue only happens when I try and knit the document. So I'm not sure why this is happening, but I appreciate you letting me know that it does knit on your computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for raw LaTeX. The following knits fine and produces the result that I think you want to achieve:

````
---
title: "Minimal Document"
author: Aiden Kenny
date: Friday, 09/21/2018
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: margin=1in 
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
---

\newpage

```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 10, fig.height = 5, echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
```

1. Here is a sample of some code I found online. The code chunk by 
itself will run fine, so that is not the issue.


```{r}
require(stats); require(graphics)
plot(cars, xlab = "Speed (mph)", ylab = "Stopping distance (ft)",
 las = 1)
lines(lowess(cars$speed, cars$dist, f = 2/3, iter = 3), col = "red")
title(main = "cars data")
plot(cars, xlab = "Speed (mph)", ylab = "Stopping distance (ft)",
     las = 1, log = "xy")
title(main = "cars data (logarithmic scales)")
lines(lowess(cars$speed, cars$dist, f = 2/3, iter = 3), col = "red")
summary(fm1 <- lm(log(dist) ~ log(speed), data = cars))
opar <- par(mfrow = c(2, 2), oma = c(0, 0, 1.1, 0),
            mar = c(4.1, 4.1, 2.1, 1.1))
plot(fm1)
par(opar)
```

2. Thanks for the help. This document will not knit!
````

As an alternative you could also use the full commands: `\begin{enumerate}` and `\end{enumerate}`. I am not sure why your abbreviations are getting stripped from the TeX file by `pandoc`.

Comment: Even when I use the full commands, I still get the error message. I will look more into Pandoc being the problem; this is the first I have ever heard of it. Thanks!

Comment: @AidenKenny For debugging it is often helpful to add `keep_tex: yes`. That way you can easily debug the LaTeX file created by pandoc.

Comment: Okay, where would I add this in my document? The setup chunk?

Comment: @AidenKenny I have added it to my example. BTW, does the not produce what you are after? As I said, for things like this raw LaTeX should not be necessary.

Comment: Your example does do what I want. I just want to figure out why the LaTeX is not working, since it had been working for so long. I have been using LaTeX longer than R, and so I guess I just prefer its use over R, but I will adapt if this issue cannot be fixed. I added `keep_tex: yes` as you did, but that really did not do anything; the document starts to knit and then the error message comes up.

Comment: @AidenKenny It is only for debugging. The directory with your Rmd file will now also contain the tex file that was produced as an intermediate step. If you are using RStudio: Which version? Did you upgrade recently?

Comment: Ah, okay, I have the .tex file in my directory. I will look over through that to see if anything is happening. I am using R Studio daily build version 1.2.2007. I have a Windows, and so the default R Studio is tediously slow on my laptop, but with the daily build it is significantly faster. I had actually factory reset my laptop last night in an attempt to fix this problem, so I believe this is the most up-to-date version of R Studio available for Windows.